# Postgresql: syntax error at or near "DELIMITER"

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to write simple stored function in postgresql But I am getting syntax error. Can any one tell me why I am getting error here?

**Stored Function**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION findAccount() RETURNS VOID
AS $$
BEGIN
select * from account;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql; $$
```

**Error**

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DELIMITER"
LINE 1: DELIMITER $$
        ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 1
```

Comment: what is `DELIMITER` supposed to do here?  Is this copied from some other SQL dialect?  IIRC that's a MySQL-specific thing

Answer (score 4):

Remove `DELIMITER $$` and the last `$$`. This isn't MySQL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION findAccount() RETURNS VOID
AS $$
BEGIN
select * from account;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

That will solve the syntax error problem.

But your function doesn't seem to do anything useful. And the `SELECT` without target variables will throw an error when you execute the function.

> ERROR: query has no destination for result data
>   SQL state: 42601
>   Hint: If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
>   Context: PL/pgSQL function findaccount() line 3 at SQL statement

But I guess that's beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: its working thank you. I have to convert more than 100 sql stored procedure into postgres .Above sql stored procedure I converted into  postgres using sqlines  online converter `http://www.sqlines.com/online`. you know any other tool for conversion

Comment: @SpringUser: Sorry, no, I don't. But I'm also skeptic about such toll being able to work a 100%. At least some need for manual conversion will remain I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the line with `DELIMITER $$` PostgreSQL does not have that syntax, instead it allows the $$ format you are using out of the box: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING